# Jquery Jplayer with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jplayer

Am using jplayer with jsource.js as source for music files but with this, i can not run php code in a js file, so, i tried to copy the source code as below to index.php and put it under  code here  inorder to run php code with in javascript but the player is not running. here is my code snippet.

Before PHP (under jsource.js file)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ========= jPlayer Album Detail Page ==========
    var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jplayer",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp-container"
    }, [

        {
            artist: "Klepic",
            title:"<span>10.</span> Hall of Fame ft. will.i.am",
            mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg",
            duration: '5:30'
        }
    ], {
        swfPath: "assets/jplayer/jplayer",
        supplied: "oga, mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        size: {width: "100%"}
    });
    // Show The Current Track !!
    $("#jplayer").on($.jPlayer.event.ready, function (event) {
        var current = myPlaylist.current;
        var playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;       
        $.each(playlist, function (index, obj) {
            if (index == current) {
                $("#playing").html("<span class='artist-name'>" + obj.artist + "</span>" + "<br>" + "<span class='track-name'>" + obj.title + "</span>");
            }
        });
    });
    $("#jplayer").on($.jPlayer.event.play, function (event) {
        var current = myPlaylist.current;
        var playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;       
        $.each(playlist, function (index, obj) {
            if (index == current) {
                $("#playing").html("<span class='artist-name'>" + obj.artist + "</span>" + "<br>" + "<span class='track-name'>" + obj.title + "</span>");
            }
        });
    });

});//
```

Under index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ========= jPlayer Album Detail Page ==========
    var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jplayer",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp-container"
    }, [
        {
            artist: "Gibson", // the artist name
            title:"<?php print $music_file->title ?>", // track title
            mp3:"<?php print $music_file->title ?>.mp3",// mp3 path
            oga:"<?php print $music_file->title ?>.ogg",// oga path
            duration: '5:12'// duration time in playlist
        }

    ], {
        swfPath: "assets/jplayer/jplayer",
        supplied: "oga, mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        size: {width: "100%"}
    });
    // Show The Current Track !!
    $("#jplayer").on($.jPlayer.event.ready, function (event) {
        var current = myPlaylist.current;
        var playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;       
        $.each(playlist, function (index, obj) {
            if (index == current) {
                $("#playing").html("<span class='artist-name'>" + obj.artist + "</span>" + "<br>" + "<span class='track-name'>" + obj.title + "</span>");
            }
        });
    });
    $("#jplayer").on($.jPlayer.event.play, function (event) {
        var current = myPlaylist.current;
        var playlist = myPlaylist.playlist;       
        $.each(playlist, function (index, obj) {
            if (index == current) {
                $("#playing").html("<span class='artist-name'>" + obj.artist + "</span>" + "<br>" + "<span class='track-name'>" + obj.title + "</span>");
            }
        });
    });

});//]]>

    </script>
```

Any help is welcomed

Comment: Got any errors in the console?

Comment: m getting this error "Update Required To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your Flash plugin." but i dont think its associated with the version of flash player, because in the first instance, the playe works so perfectly

Comment: view the source your php file generated, specifically check the lines after `artist: "Gibson",`

Comment: That part is ok

Comment: Are you sure? This is the only part that might change...